# is it possible to get the User (or userid) who authored a change to an ExpandoValue instance/record?

Tags: java, liferay

In Liferay 5.2.x, I'm trying to get the User or userid of the person who did something which triggered a change in an `ExpandoValue` instance/record.  Is this possible?

The custom attribute/expando data model is represented by `ExpandoTable`, `ExpandoColumn`, `ExpandoRow`, and `ExpandoValue`.  `ExpandoValue` does not appear to have a field to track who made the last change.  What would I need to do to add one?  Is this a good idea?

Alternatively, I have an `ExpandoValueListener` model listener.  Model Listeners seems to be divorced from any particular Request though, because listener methods get fired "reactively" to changes in the model.  None of the method headers in the `ModelListener` interface contain a Request of any kind, or even a ServiceContext (built off of a Request).

Still, is there a way to access the Request, or ServiceContext, or some other mechanism to get the current UserId from within any ModelListener method (perhaps one of the `onBefore*()` methods?  I've seen some people recommend using `PrincipalThreadLocal` but that seems to return `null` sometimes.

Any ideas?  Do i need to just trap the button click instead?  I'm trying to avoid that because it's messy and harder to maintain than, say, a DB trigger or model listener.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like a way to [access ServiceContext from within a ModelListener](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-10238) may have been added to Liferay 6.0.3.  That may help someone else, but upgrading is not an option for me at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Liferay 6 solves this problem by adding a `ServiceContextThreadLocal` class that holds a stack of `ServiceContext`s.  Also, `BasePersistenceImpl` contains a

`public T update(T model, boolean merge, ServiceContext serviceContext)`

convenience method that pushes the context, fires the model listener, and then pops the context.  The idea is that you can get the `ServiceContext` from the `ServiceContextThreadLocal` now, within the `ModelListener` being implemented.

I'm not going to try to mimic this in Liferay 5.2.x, because it's beyond the scope of my project to modify the persistence layer in this manner.  At the end of the day, i think i'm just going to call a stored proc from the struts processAction when the button is clicked.

This is perhaps the worst way to handle this, from a code maintenance and readability perspective, but also contributing to this decision is the fact that i have only three such events, and I'm quite short on time.  Hopefully I can fold these into the modelListener / serviceContext if or when I can upgrade to Liferay 6.